# How to link javascript in different domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need link to my `test.js` file to my website from different webiste.

I cant use `domain.com/test.js`

but

I want use `domain.com` for link to my js file

Can I do this ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27404921/3454593

Comment: Check the full path of the JS file from the Developer Console of the browser, maybe its not in domain.com/test.js but it can be something like domain.com/assets/js/test.js

Answer (score 1):

for this you need to add the url in html using script tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry for this bad question.

So i try put question again...

I have 2 domains.

domain.com -> where i have this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
<div> TEST </div>

<script src="https://domain2.com/test.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

So in domain.com link to javascript from second domain and work good.

But i need this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>

<body>
<div> TEST </div>

<script src="https://domain2.com"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

link to js like a domain2.com/test.js but i need load js only from domain2.com

Can i do this ?

Comment: Add this as an edit to your question, not put it down as an answer