# React js : Call the function from external js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to call the function from external js file, the file is some where in network, I tried to add this to `index.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../example.js"></script>
```

In my one the react js class `sample.js`, I want to call the function `funA` from this external js file, I tried with `window.funA()`, but it's throwing error that not defined.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27403797/can-a-javascript-hosted-on-different-domain-read-modify-dom-of-another-domain

Comment: I think the link is something different, and believe that I am doing something wrong while invoking the function.